Lemonade stand in ledger cli
The Accounting Game
There's a book that introduces accounting called The Accounting Game by Mullis and Orloff:

ledger-cli file
Here's one approach to implementing the transactions from chapter 1 in ledger-cli:
2024/01/01   original investment
    assets:cash  5
    liabilities:owners equity:original investment

2024/01/02   loan from parents
    assets:cash  10
    liabilities:notes payable

2024/01/03   buy materials
    assets:inventory  12
    assets:cash

2024/01/04   sales
    assets:cash  25
    assets:inventory  -10
    liabilities:owners equity:earnings week to date

2024/01/05   expenses
    assets:cash  -5
    liabilities:owners equity:earnings week to date

2024/01/05   pay off loan
    liabilities:notes payable  10
    assets:cash

Chapter 1 balance sheet
At the end of chapter 1, here's the balance sheet we end up with:

If we run ledger on the file, we get:
$ ledger -f lemonade.ledger balance
                  15  assets
                  13    cash
                   2    inventory
                 -15  liabilities:owners equity
                 -10    earnings week to date
                  -5    original investment
--------------------
                   0

Which appears to match up with the book's balance sheet.
Question : expenses
At one point in the chapter, some expenses are tracked:

I implemented this transaction as follows:
2024/01/05   expenses
    assets:cash  -5
    liabilities:owners equity:earnings week to date

While this does result in a balanced sheet, the actual expenses (glass rental, advertising, rent) aren't reflected in the balance sheet or in the ledger file.
What's a good way to track this in the ledger file and still end up with a balanced sheet?
Update 1
In a comment below, Hart CO mentions that chapter 2 discusses the income statement. Here's the income statement from chapter 2:

And the ending balance sheet:

Here's a ledger file that incorporates the expenses:
2024/01/01   original investment
    assets:cash  5
    liabilities:owners equity:original investment

2024/01/02   loan from parents
    assets:cash  10
    liabilities:notes payable

2024/01/03   buy materials
    assets:inventory:lemons  10
    assets:inventory:sugar  2
    assets:cash

2024/01/04   sales
    assets:cash  25
    assets:inventory  -10
    liabilities:owners equity:earnings week to date

2024/01/05   expenses
    expenses:glass rental  2
    expenses:advertising  1
    expenses:rent  2
    assets:cash

2024/01/06   pay off loan
    liabilities:notes payable  10
    assets:cash

I get $15 in the assets, which is correct. However, I'm getting -20 for liabilities:
$ ledger -f lemonade-income-statement.ledger balance
                  15  assets
                  13    cash
                   2    inventory
                  10      lemons
                   2      sugar
                   5  expenses
                   1    advertising
                   2    glass rental
                   2    rent
                 -20  liabilities:owners equity
                 -15    earnings week to date
                  -5    original investment
--------------------
                   0


I think you'll learn about expense accounts/income statement in chapter 2.

Hey @HartCO ‍♂️. Yup, I just read through chapter 2. I've updated the question to show the relevant income statement. I've also included a ledger file that incorporates the expenses. However, I'm not sure is the approach I'm using there is the recommended approach.

This is an accounting question not obviously linked to personal finance. It risks being closed for that reason.

You're confusing income statements with balance sheets, and expenses with assets and liabilities. Expenses decrease assets and/or increase liabilities.

@littleadv I've added an answer that incorporates expenses and everything balances out. Not sure if this is considered the idiomatic approach, but it seems to work.

@HartCO I've added an answer that incorporates expenses and everything balances out. Not sure if this is considered the idiomatic approach, but it seems to work.

For downvoters, here's one of the previous ledger-cli-tagged questions where there seemed to be consensus that ledger-cli / plain text accounting questions are on topic here.

Questions related to personal finance are on topic here. Accounting questions related to running a business are not. I submit that this specific question is on the wrong side of that line; it's about business accounting, not personal accounting.

@keshlam surely a lemonade stand would be a sole trader :-)

@GS-ApologisetoMonica: ... Sole proprietor, probably. But if they're big enough to need bookkeeping - as some are, admittedly - then they are starting to get out of the range of personal finance. But rather than grump further, I am just going to hide all references to ledger - CLI so I'm not tempted to respond to them. –
keshlam

Here's one approach which incorporates expenses:
2020-01-01 initial investment
    assets:cash  5
    liabilities:owner equity:initial investment

2020-01-02 loan from parents
    assets:cash  10
    liabilities:notes payable:parents

2020-01-03 buy lemons
    lemons  10
    assets:cash

2020-01-03 buy sugar
    sugar  2
    assets:cash

2020-01-03 make lemonade
    assets:lemonade
    lemons  -10
    sugar    -2

2020-01-03 sell lemonade
    assets:cash       25
    assets:lemonade  -10
    liabilities:owner equity:profit

2020-01-04  pay for glass rental
    expenses:glass rental  2
    assets:cash

2020-01-05  pay for sign
    expenses:sign  1
    assets:cash

2020-01-06  pay rent
    expenses:rent  2
    assets:cash

2020-01-07  pay back loan
    liabilities:notes payable:parents  10
    assets:cash

2020-01-08  adjust profit for glass rental
    liabilities:owner equity:profit  2
    expenses:glass rental

2020-01-08  adjust profit for sign
    liabilities:owner equity:profit  1
    expenses:sign

2020-01-08  adjust profit for rent
    liabilities:owner equity:profit  2
    expenses:rent

Balance at the end:
$ ledger -f lemonade-003-tagged.dat b
                  15  assets
                  13    cash
                   2    lemonade
                 -15  liabilities:owner equity
                  -5    initial investment
                 -10    profit
--------------------
                   0

Note that I can also show balances before the expenses were taken out of profits, so we can see what they were at that point in time:
$ ledger -f lemonade-003-tagged.dat b --end 2020-01-07
                  25  assets
                  23    cash
                   2    lemonade
                   5  expenses
                   2    glass rental
                   2    rent
                   1    sign
                 -30  liabilities
                 -10    notes payable:parents
                 -20    owner equity
                  -5      initial investment
                 -15      profit
--------------------
                   0

